# Pandas Compare two columns matching text and printing full row of matching

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to take a hash from one df and find that hash in another df.hash column and print the full row of the matches.

df1:

`hash
11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b1
11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b2
11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b3
11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b4`

df2:

`filepath          hash
C:\windows        11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b5
C:\Temp           11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b6
C:\foundya        11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b1
C:\Windows\temp   11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b2`

Expected output:

`filepath          hash
C:\foundya        11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b1
C:\Windows\temp   11dd7da7faa0130dac2560930e90c8b2`

Failed Attempts:

`print(df2[['hash','filepath']][~df2['hash'].isin(df1)])
print(df2[['hash','filepath']][~df1.isin(df2['hash'])])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about a simple merge here?

```
df1.merge(df2, on ='hash', how ='inner')
```

Comment: If this were to be amplified by say 44 million rows, would this be efficient?This does work great, I was just thinking the merge would take a bit more resources. Thanks very much.

Comment: `merge` is very efficient, dont worry.